# Show that the function is strictly increasing.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, functions

How should I show that the function $f$ defined below is strictly increasing for $x\in(0,1)$?

I have considered its first derivative, but it seems too complicated to deduce $f'>0$ from there.

$f(x)=\frac{3x^2+4x(1-x)+4(1-x)^2}{4x^2}\ln^2{(1-x)}$

$f'(x)=\dfrac{\ln\left(1-x\right)\left(3x^3+\left(2\ln\left(1-x\right)-4\right)x^2+\left(4-6\ln\left(1-x\right)\right)x+4\ln\left(1-x\right)\right)}{2\left(x-1\right)x^3}$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Have you tried taylor/Maclaurin expansion of $\ln^2(1-x)$?

Comment: @AdamRubinson Yes I have considered the two terms Maclaurin expansion of $\ln^2{(1-x)}$ and $f'>0$ follows. However, I'm not sure whether this approach is convincing/rigorous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$(1-x+\frac{3}{4}x^2)\left(\frac{\log(1-x)}{x}\right)^2=(1-x+\frac{3}{4}x^2)\left(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^i}{i+1}\right)^2=(1-x+\frac{3}{4}x^2)\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_kx^k=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}b_kx^k$$ with $$a_k=\sum_{i=0}^k\frac{1}{(i+1)(k+1-i)}=\frac{2}{k+2}\sum_{i=0}^k\frac{1}{i+1}$$ and $b_0=1$, $b_1=0$ and $b_{k+2}=a_{k+2}-a_{k+1}+\frac{3}{4}a_k.$ Just now prove peacefully that $b_{k+2}\geq 0$ for $k\geq 0.$

Comment: Hi @Gérard. Thank you for your elegant approach!